# Blackberry setting a clipping region/area

Tags: optimization, graphics, blackberry, clipping

In J2ME we have the clipRect() and setClip() to clip a region in the Graphics area. What is the equivalent apis available in BlackBerry and how do we use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the blackberry API. pushRegion() for the clipRect(), don't know of exact setClip replacement.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.6api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html

Comment: Actually I found that out in the Graphics class itself, if you provide the width, height and the offsets in the drawBitmap method, it automatically clips and anything beyond that width and height will not be painted or rather gets cropped